# How to update config file through Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I want to update my .conf file but whatever I do it wont get updated? What is the solution?

**The dockerfile is simple as this now:**

```
FROM nginx:latest

COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

**Just wanted to change the root folder and therefore need to update it.**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html/public;
    index index.html index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: "whatever I do it wont get updated" — So what exactly are you doing?

Comment: docker build -t containerid .  I want my index file to start from a public folder. thats it.

Comment: try to set user `USER root`

Comment: Are you building dockerfile from directory in which updated default.conf file is available?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your Dockerfile that I can see; when I replicate it with a basic conf file it all works as expected:

```
> echo 'FROM nginx:latest' > Dockerfile
> echo 'COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf' >> Dockerfile
> echo 'server {}' > default.conf
> docker build -t temp .
```

Builds correctly, and the file is copied to the image:

```
> docker run temp cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
server {}
```

What's the output from your `docker build` command?